# Docker build: error: ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE: MySQL client

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

When I try `docker-compose -f docker-compose-now.yml up` I get this message

```
error: ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client
```

Now, I did read this solution:

```
use mysql;
update user set authentication_string=password(''), plugin='mysql_native_password' where user='root';
```

from: https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/1507

but how can I put it in my `docker-compose-now.yml` file in `entrypoints`?

My environment is in this file, and when I try:

```
entrypoints: sh "update user set authentication_string=password(''), plugin='mysql_native_password' where user='root'"
```

I only get another error.

How can I resolve this please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Problem

To put things in perspective, what you're doing in your entry point script is actually being executed in the `sh` shell. The commands you want to run should be executed inside a `mysql` shell.

### Solution

Your entrypoint should have the following command instead to run the `mysql` commands:

```
mysql -u root -p [root-password] -e "update user set authentication_string=password(''), plugin='mysql_native_password' where user='root';"
```

If you wanna do this on `mysql` db, you can do

```
mysql -u root -p [root-password] mysql -e "update user set authentication_string=password(''), plugin='mysql_native_password' where user='root';"
```

### Explanation

In this command, first you enter in mysql shell using `mysql -u -p` command and then you execute the sql command using `-e` flag(it stands for execute). Whatever comes after `-e` is executed in mysql shell (like queries etc). For details and examples, refer to this:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/command-line-options.html

Comment: Should it be first `sh`, then `mysql -u root -p [root-password] mysql -e "update user set authentication_string=password(''), plugin='mysql_native_password' where user='root';"
`?

Comment: Also, what is `-e` please?

Comment: Updated the answer @JohnSam

Answer (score 5):

```
version: '3'

services:

  db:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWOR=example
```

I found solution on Docker hub in mysql image. Its set "command" for docker-compose.yml that change mode of auth.

Comment: Providing code with no explanation is not a good answer. Edit your answer so that everyone can understand what is the solution provided please.

Comment: I allow you to do it for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by adding this line to my docker-compose.yml file

- MYSQL_AUTHENTICATION_PLUGIN=mysql_native_password

This is an example of my file now:

```html
version: '1.8'
name: my_docker_db
services:
  mysql:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/mysql:8.0
    container_name: my_db
    networks:
      - mayo1NetWrok
    ports:
      - '33066:3306'
    volumes:
      - ./database/data:/bitnami/mysql/data
      - ./database/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    environment:
      # ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD is recommended only for development.
      #- ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - MYSQL_AUTHENTICATION_PLUGIN=mysql_native_password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=
      - MYSQL_USER=
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    healthcheck:
      test: ['CMD', '/opt/bitnami/scripts/mysql/healthcheck.sh']
      interval: 15s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 6  
networks:
  myNetWrok:
```